# why rstudio is not showing any gui in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, rstudio

I am using Rstudio. It is not showing any gui elements like editor, menu options etc when i am using it via my user whereas if I use it via sudo command it is working and showing these components. I reinstalled it by removing it by apt-get command, still the problem did not go. Please tell the solution to this problem
[rstudio image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLZnd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I removed this directory and it worked ~/.rstudio-desktop.

> It looks like RStudio is having trouble writing to your home directory 
>   (/home/sn). Any chance your quota is full, or you're starting RStudio
>   with lower permissions?
>
> Failing that, try removing the folder ~/.rstudio-desktop.

source: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203007656-Rstudio-starts-up-but-only-shows-menus?page=1#community_comment_210307427